# Barriers or semaphores for multiple submissions over the same queue?

Tags: vulkan

In this example where we copy some buffer into vertex buffer and we want to quickly to start rendering using this buffer in two submissions without waiting over some fence:

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer(tansferCommandBuffer)
  vkCmdCopyBuffer(tansferCommandBuffer, hostVisibleBuffer, vertexBuffer)
vkEndCommandBuffer(tansferCommandBuffer)

vkQueueSubmit(queue, tansferCommandBuffer)


vkBeginCommandBuffer(renderCommandBuffer)
  ...
  vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(vertexBuffer)
  vkCmdDraw()
  ...
vkEndCommandBuffer(renderCommandBuffer)

vkQueueSubmit(queue, renderCommandBuffer)
```

From what I understand is that `tansferCommandBuffer` might not have been finished when `renderCommandBuffer` is submitted, and `renderCommandBuffer` may get scheduled and reads form floating data in `vertexBuffer`.

We could attach a semaphore while submitting `tansferCommandBuffer` to be singled after completion and forward this semaphore to `renderCommandBuffer` to wait for before execution. The issue here is that it blocks the second batch commands that do not depend on the buffer.

Or we could insert a barrier after the copy command or before the bind vertex command, which seems to be much better since we can specify that the access to the buffer is our main concerned and possibly keep part of the batch to be executed.

Is there any good reason for using semaphores instead of barriers for similar cases (single queue, multiple submissions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barriers are necessary whenever you change the way in which resources are used to inform the driver/hardware about that change. So in your example the barrier is probably needed too, nevertheless.

But as for the semaphores. When you submit a command buffer, you specify both semaphore handles and pipeline stages at which wait should occur on a corresponding semaphore. You do this through the following members of the VkSubmitInfo structure:

> - pWaitSemaphores is a pointer to an array of semaphores upon which to wait before the command buffers for this batch begin execution. If
>     semaphores to wait on are provided, they define a semaphore wait
>     operation.
> - pWaitDstStageMask is a pointer to an array of pipeline stages at which each corresponding semaphore wait will occur.

So when you submit a command buffer, all commands up to the specified stage can be executed by the hardware.

Comment: Could you please rephrase _"So in You example the barrier is probably need nevertheless."_ with more assertion, If you are saying it is not needed, doesn't the copy operation change the resource?

Comment: I meant "is needed too" (I rephrased the answer to correct typos). Yes, In Vulkan when You copy something to (or from) a resource and then use it for some other purpose (for example as the mentioned vertex buffer) these usages are different and You need to synchronize such operations using barriers.

Comment: Thanks! but is there a good reason why would we use semaphores instead of barriers, assuming we are tracking resources and their changes? (I suppose that barriers are much lighter than semaphore?)

Comment: Spec is quite clear here:

"- Barrier is a synchronization command that inserts a dependency between commands submitted to the same queue, or between commands in the same subpass.
- Semaphores are a synchronization primitive that can be used to insert a dependency between batches submitted to queues."

So barriers synchronizes operations, let's say, internally (inside the same queue) and tell the driver that resources have changed. Semaphores are used for synchronization between different queues (or other, independent parts of hardware/driver like presentation engine).

Comment: Are these independent parts defined in the specs?

Comment: Yes. One is in the section about barriers and the second in the section about semaphores ;-).